# MS Word document as T4 template

Tags: templates, ms-word, t4

I want to embed a T4 template using Custom Content Controls within MS Word.  The following picture says it all:

*<< Insufficeint repuation post images: 
Imagine a MS Word document with Custom Content Controls containing the T4 markup.  Very simple. I'll add the images as soon as I can. >>*

I'm using Office 2010 with developer mode turned on.

Of interest, for a few differenc customers I have used the Custom Content Controls but embedded XSL/XPath queries into them.  That works well, but needs fairly well structured XML to work efficiently.

*<< Insufficeint repuation post images: 
Imagine a MS Word document with Custom Content Controls containing XPath Queries.  Includes XSLT style for-each() loops and value-of() >>*

It is really simple to implement the document processor using Word.Interop - a parser for the above diagram took about 3 hours beginning to end.  Using T4 however is not quite so simple.

The approach I'm considering is using the serialised word document, and replacing the custom controls with T4 markup (generating a T4 template) and feeding that to the T4 compiler.  That would be quite a bit of work.  Manipulating a serialised word document would be pretty hard.

**Some possible approaches:**

1. Try to convert OpenXML document to generate T4 template which, when processed, will
   generate an OpenXML document.  In the middle of this, all the CustomContentControls get substituted for T4 templates.  This really sounds like a great way to generate corrupted documents.
2. Try to get T4 compiler to interact with some OpenXML SDK.  Can't see any way this could work.
3. Try to get T4 compiler to interact with Word.Interop.  Can't see any way this could work.
4. Try to convince Microsoft that this is such a great (fun) idea that many customers would like.

**So, my question(s) are:**

1. Does there exist a tool to do this?, if not,
2. Is there a simple approach I could take to do this?, if not,
3. Could I convince someone else out there to take on such a fun challenge?

Of interest, I've been using T4 templates for quite a while now and find them excellent.  In generating documentations in the past I have used the T4 to generate XML, then linked the XML into MS Word template to generate the document.  All wrapped up in a MSBuild script we have a complete build process, including customer facing documentation, for our software.